# Is there any StringBuilder or StringBuffer implementation in MQL4 for a fast string append?

Tags: mql4

Is there something like a `StringBuilder` (Java) or `StringBuffer` (C#) in MQL4 that facilitates fast string append?

Answer (score 0):

The `StringConcatenate( str1, str2, ..., strN )` seems to be the fastest.
Haven't seen any implementation of the builder in the MQL4 articles or in the include / classes.